# Change color of button when <select> is selected

Tags: angularjs

everyone!I'm just new in stackoverflow.com. I have a problem below:

1) HTML:
  1.1) :

```
<select class="fm_textbox" name="sltGender" ng-model="measurementsForm.gender" ng-class="{'fm_error':measurementsForm.error_gender}" ng-change="change_state(0, measurementsForm.gender)">
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option value="woman">Femme</option>
                                <option value="man">Homme</option>
                            </select>
```

1.2) :

```
<button type="submit" class="fm_button" my-button="measurementsForm.gender != ''">CALCULER MA TAILLE</button>
```

2) directive.js:

```
angular.module('FitManagerApp.directives', []).directive('myButton',  function(){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        myButton: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        if (!myButton) {
            element.css('background-color', 'red');
        }
        else {
            element.css('background-color', 'black');
        }
    }
};
```

});

I also have a controller.js containing the variable : measurementsForm.gender.
I want my color to be black when my  has a value. If not, that's red.
Before i post this question, i have searched many question concerning to "Communication directive controller", i used the "=" like they recommanded but that didn't work.

Comment: Why did it not display my word "Hello"? T_T

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have also tried that befor but it didn't work. But I have resolved my problem by this way: 

    scope.$watch('myButton', function(v) {
    if (!v) {
     element.css('background-color', 'red');
    }
    else {
     element.css('background-color', 'black');
    }
   });

Comment: I'm just new, so i can't reply after 8 hours since my post :(

Comment: Are you building the directive solely to achieve this css result?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a variable `myButton` in your link function, you need to check if `!scope.myButton`, so your link function will look like:

```
if (!$scope.myButton) {
   element.css('background-color', 'red');
}
else {
   element.css('background-color', 'black');
}
```